# Incorrect argument using Opus.NET when Encoding

Tags: c#, opus

I was using [Opus.NET](https://github.com/DevJohnC/Opus.NET) and successfully encoded Audio with their default Demo Project with default sampling rate `48000`. When I am trying to change the sampling rate to `8000` I get Opus Encoding error.

I am sure this has to do with `segmentFrames` plus `Bitrate` must be changed accordingly. I am unable to make this calculation here is my code from default Opus.NET demo project at [GitHub](https://github.com/DevJohnC/Opus.NET).

Here is the code

```c#
void StartEncoding()
{
    _startTime = DateTime.Now;
    _bytesSent = 0;
    _segmentFrames = 960;
    _encoder = OpusEncoder.Create(48000, 1,   FragLabs.Audio.Codecs.Opus.Application.Voip);
    _encoder.Bitrate = 8192;
    _decoder = OpusDecoder.Create(48000, 1);
    _bytesPerSegment = _encoder.FrameByteCount(_segmentFrames);

    _waveIn = new WaveIn(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
    _waveIn.BufferMilliseconds = 25;
    _waveIn.DeviceNumber = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    _waveIn.DataAvailable += _waveIn_DataAvailable;
    _waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(48000, 16, 1);

    _playBuffer = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(48000, 16, 1));

    _waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
    _waveOut.DeviceNumber = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;
    _waveOut.Init(_playBuffer);

    _waveOut.Play();
    _waveIn.StartRecording();

    if (_timer == null)
    {
        _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
    }
    _timer.Start();
}
```

Every time I encode by changing the values from `48000` to `8000` I get error at Opus saying

> Encoded Error arguments are incorrect

Comment: Bit rate is wrong.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV

Comment: I know the bit rate is wrong if I change it to 8000 Samples it cannot be 8192 and also segmentFrames also need to change from 960 to something.. but what is the question. Link you have provided does not have this info.

Comment: The latency listed here is the total delay (frame size, plus all lookahead) at the normal operating sample rate (typically 44.1 kHz).  See webpage : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_audio_coding_formats

Answer (score 3):

Your sampling rate can be one of `[8, 12, 16, 24, 48] kHz`, so 8kHz is ok.

Value of `_segmentFrames` depends on your sampling rate and size of opus frame (in milliseconds). Possible sizes are `[2.5, 5, 10, 20, 40, 60] ms`, default is 20ms. So here is how 960 calculated:

SampleRate / 1000 * FrameSize = 48000 / 1000 * 20 = 960

If you want your rate to be 8kHz, `_segmentFrames` should be `8000 / 1000 * 20 = 160`.

`_encoder.Bitrate` can be any of `6-510 kbs`.

More info: https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/view/opus/job/opus/ws/doc/html/group__opus__encoder.html